# How do correclty set a numeric interval with square brackets through siunitx package?

Tags: math-mode, siunitx, sirange, numrange

I'm using overleaf with `pdfLaTex` compiler and I want to get a numeric range like this: [first_value,end_value]. I tried the following code by setting the `siunitx` package properties but the output is not the desidered one because the square brackets are not shown:

```
\documentclass[11pt,oneside]{book}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\sisetup{
  inter-unit-product={\,},
  number-unit-product={\,},
  output-decimal-marker = {.},
  exponent-product={\cdot},
  group-separator={},
  group-four-digits=false,
  range-phrase = \ {,}\ ,  
  range-units = brackets,  
  open-bracket = \[,        
  close-bracket =\],        
  round-mode=places,  
}

\begin{document}

$\numrange[round-precision=8]{3.00058228}{3.00089684}$


\end{document}
```

Can you help me?

Comment: Just put `range-phrase={,}` and put `[` and `]` around it yourself (or with a custom macro). I don't see an option with `siunitx` to enclose a range in something.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Qrrbrbirlbel, I don't manage to use the brackets with `\numrange` , can you show an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I see it, `siunitx` doesn't has the functionality to specify a custom set of brackets to wrap around it.

The various `bracket` options for `range-exponents`, `list-units`, `product-units` and `range-units` seem to be only an option when you factor out exponents or common units. I couldn't find the options `open-bracket` and `close-bracket` at all in the `siunitx` manual.

(In any case, `\[` and `\]` are LaTeX macros to start and end display-math blocks, equivalent to the `equation` environment of `amsmath`.)

I'd just define my own range macro that automatically wraps `[` and `]` around the `\…range` macros.

Of course, if you need to use other ranges in your document you could set `range-phrase` and `range-units` inside of these custom macros.

### Code

```
\documentclass[11pt,oneside]{book}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\sisetup{
  inter-unit-product={\,},
  number-unit-product={\,},
  output-decimal-marker = {.},
  exponent-product={\cdot},
  group-separator={},
  group-four-digits=false,
  range-phrase = \ensuremath{,{}}, % ensuring proper spacing around ,
  range-units = repeat,
  round-mode=places,
}
\newcommand*{\Range}[3][]{[\numrange[#1]{#2}{#3}]}
\newcommand*{\RangeUnits}[4][]{[\qtyrange[#1]{#2}{#3}{#4}]}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{lll}
Mode & \ttfamily\string\numrange & \ttfamily\string\qtyrange \\
Math: & $\Range[round-precision=8]{3.00058228}{3.00089684}$
      & $\RangeUnits[round-precision=8]{3.00058228}{3.00089684}{\metre}$ \\
Text: & \Range{123}{456}         & \RangeUnits{123}{456}{\metre}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Since I use a modular Overleaf project, my preamble is in a different `.tex` file called `_units.tex` where I have the call to `siunitx` and its setup, do I have to put those `\newcommand`  below `\usepackage{siunitx}` or where?

Comment: @Giuseppe They don't need to be below it but from an organizing aspect it'd be more logical.